# Elasticsearch: order by length of array properties

Tags: java, sql, json, elasticsearch, search

im using Kibana and ES, i have an index with objects and an array called "reviews" that inside has properties called positive_comment, negative_comment, reviewer_name and more.

There are some reviews that have the field positive_comment empty (not null, just empty).

I need to order by the length of the field positive_comment first, so reviews with empty positive_comment comes last. The results are the same when ordering in SQL with LEN() property.

This is my query.
I also tried:
.value.size() in the script, or type "string" but no results.

```
{
   "_source":[
      "reviews.positive_comment"
   ],
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "filter":[
            {
               "term":{
                  "id":214
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "sort":{
      "_script":{
         "script":"doc['reviews.positive_comment'].value.length()",
         "type":"number",
         "order":"asc"
      }
   }
}
```

This is my result:

```
{
   "_source":{
      "reviews":[
         {
            "positive_comment":"Great"
         },
         {
            "positive_comment":"Really good product"
         },
         {
            "positive_comment":""
         },
         {
            "positive_comment":""
         },
         {
            "positive_comment":""
         },
         {
            "positive_comment":""
         },
         {
            "positive_comment":""
         },
         {
            "positive_comment":""
         },
         {
            "positive_comment":""
         },
         {
            "positive_comment":""
         },
         {
            "positive_comment":""
         },
         {
            "positive_comment":""
         },
         {
            "positive_comment":""
         },
         {
            "positive_comment":""
         },
         {
            "positive_comment":""
         },
         {
            "positive_comment":"Awesome"
         }
      ]
   },
   "sort":[
      "0"
   ]
}
```

Comment: With `scripted_field` first check if `doc['reviews.positive_comment'].value` gives you correct value or not. If it does, then add handling for null values too..

Comment: @ms_27 If i run this query: "script_fields": {
    "test_script": {
      "script": {
        "inline": "doc['reviews.positive_comment'].value",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  }

The result is ""

Comment: can you share sample document and your index mapping?

Comment: @ms_27 `"reviews": [ { "item_id": 214, "year": 1990, "date_created": "2021-07-21T15:05:41.103", "negative_comment": "Nothing", "valuation": 3, "reviewer_name": "", "positive_comment": "Awesome", "reviewer_id": 7465, "comment": "This is a comment.", "id": 1817 }]`

This is just one review from the item_id: 214

Comment: @ms_27 `"reviews": { "properties": { "positive_comment": { "type": "keyword" }`
This is the mapping of the property positive_comment of the array called reviews

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch doesn't support counting array elements, unless you use a script.

However, running a script for every matching document is going to degrade performance for every search query.

A better solution would be to count the values once, at index-time, and store the counts in dedicated fields (`positive_comments_count`, `negative_comments_count`, etc.) and use these fields for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Try following. It worked for me on ES 5.6.3. So, should work on higher versions too.

```
GET test/test/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "doc['reviews.positive_comment'].value.length()"
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tested on ES 7.1 version too.

**Mapping**

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "somefield": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "reviews": {
        "properties": {
          "positive_comment": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "item_id": {
            "type": "double"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query:**

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "_source": "reviews.positive_comment", 
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "doc['reviews.positive_comment'].value.length() % 100"
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

**output**

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "test5",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "reviews" : [
            {
              "positive_comment" : ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          0.0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "test1",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "reviews" : [
            {
              "positive_comment" : "Awesome"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          7.0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "test3",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "reviews" : [
            {
              "positive_comment" : "What a product"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          14.0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "test2",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "reviews" : [
            {
              "positive_comment" : "What a product.. amazing"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          24.0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "test4",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "reviews" : [
            {
              "positive_comment" : "Thats a great product.. "
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          24.0
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It is the same sort script as i posted, unfortunately that does not work :(
I'm using ES 6.2

Comment: No there is a difference. I have added source and lang.

Comment: Maybe i wasnt clear, but first im filtering by an item_id, then for that item_id i want all the reviews (stored in the array called reviews) ordered by length. Try to add more than 1 review in, for example, test4 and apply the sort